# IPv6 forwarding doesn't work

Tags: routing, ipv6, ping, forwarding

I have three Virtual Machines: **A**, **B**, **C**.

Machine **A** and Machine **C** connected to each other through the **B**.

Their config:

**A**'s IP: `2000::ffff:50a:b0b/120`

**C**'s IP: `2000::ffff:50a:d0d/120`

Machine **B** has two interfaces - `eth0` and `eth1`

IP of `eth0` - `2000::ffff:50a:b0c/120`

IP of `eth1` - `2000::ffff:50a:d0e/120`

I've set `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` at Machine **B**

Also, at machines **A** and **C** I've set default gateways:

At **A**

```
ip -6 ro add default via 2000::ffff:50a:b0c
```

At **C**

```
ip -6 ro add default via 2000::ffff:50a:d0e
```

I want to ping machine **C** from **A** and vice versa.
The strange thing, that most part of ICMP packets are lost with message

> Address unreachable

Comment: I instead use a bridge interface if the same subnet is on two different interfaces of a host

Comment: Which virtualization system are you using, and what type of interface (host, NAT, bridge, etc.) do the VMs have to the host?

Comment: If the addresses in your examples are the actual addresses you are using, I would strongly suggest using [Unique Local Addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) instead, and with `/64` subnets instead of `/120`.

Comment: /120 means they are in different subnets, so it's routed. Reproducing the very same configuration with 3 network namespaces (linux) works fine here.

Comment: @A.B i don't know why, but the problem was in neighbor table. I manually set mapping between ip and mac addresses and it works fine

Comment: strange I didn't have to do that to get it working. if icmpv6 is firewalled NDD fails. don't firewall icmp